# Executing commands on command prompt of a remote computer

Tags: sql, powershell, command-line

I need to execute the command :- Powermt display dev = all  in the command prompt of a remote computer. How do I do that ?

Comment: You can use PsExec to execute programs on remote computers. `psexec \\HOSTNAME powermt display dev=all`

Comment: It says network path not found , make sure that admin$ share is enabled on that remote system

Comment: Can you see that machine in `Entire Network > MS windows network`

Comment: Yes , and I have local admin permissions on the same , still doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

If you have PowerShell 2.0 or higher on both computers and can enable remoting on the remote computer by execute `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`, then from an elevated/admin PowerShell prompt you can run:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remotepcname -ScriptBlock { <commands to execute remotely> }
```

This will execute the commands remotely and return the results to the local computer.

Comment: I get an error saying A parameter cannot be found that matches Parameter name Expression

Comment: Doh, it is scriptblock.  This is one area I wish PowerShell was more consistent.

Comment: I dont think it is ScriptBlock , as executing the above command gives me the usage of powermt ... my command was :    Invoke-Command -ComputerName remotepcname -ScriptBlock { Powermt display dev = all }

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative to try where psexec and powershell fail.  It's convoluted and hackish, but at least it's something else to try.  :)

Firstly, share a folder on your own machine.  Make sure an account with admin rights on the *remote* machine has write access to this share you create.  Then execute the following:

```
wmic /node:remoteComputerAddr /user:adminOnRemoteComputer /password:adminPassword process call create "cmd.exe /c powermt display dev=all >>\\localComputerAddr\shareName\results.txt"
@type "c:\local\path\to\share\results.txt"
```

Unfortunately, `wmic` doesn't show you the output of the process it creates.  That's why you enable a share on your local workstation, then redirect the output from the remote command to your share.

[More info](http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/2009/05/episode-31-remote-command-execution.html).

Comment: share the folder with whom ? And do I create the folder on my local machine ?

Comment: @user2042493 - That's because this isn't a powershell command.  It's a Windows executable -- `c:\windows\system32\wbem\wmic.exe` to be specific.  Click the "More info" link in my answer above.  It'll explain how this is supposed to work more thoroughly than I can here.